# ¿quiero a hacer un metodo para eliminar un carro de un linkendlist pero no se como hacerlo?

Tags: java, lista, poo, arraylist, class

estoy programando un programa par agestionar el almacen de un consesionario, pero me quede atorado en el metodo para eliminar un carro o objecto del linkendlist porque primero tengo que pedirle al usuario por medio de un enumerado que elija uno de los 3 motivos por el cual se elimina ese carro o objecto y luego pedirle la marca y numero de serie del motor del carro para luego buscar dentro del linkendlist el objecto que tiene esos datos y eliminarlos, pero no he podido hacer eso podrian ayudarme?
este es el codigo para la pedida de datos del carro que es guardadfo dentro del linkenlist:

public void addCar() {

```
    int cylinder = view.readInt("Ingrese el cilindraje del carro");
    int motorSeries = view.readInt("Ingrese el numero de serie del carro");
    int modelYear = view.readInt("Ingrese el año del modelo del carro");
    String modelCar = view.readString("ingrese el modelo del carro");
    String color = view.readString("Ingrese el color del carro");
    String brand = view.readString("Ingrese la marca del carro");
    int price = view.readInt("Ingrese precio del carro");
    Car car = new Car(cylinder, motorSeries, modelYear, color, modelCar, brand, price);
    LinkedList<Car> cars = store.getCars();
    cars.add(car);
}
```

Comment: Y ahora recorres la lista, y buscas el carro... que parte no sabes hacer?? recorrer la lista???

Comment: no entiendo como hacer el numerado y tambien como recorrer la lista

Comment: empecemos por el principio.. sabes hacer una iteracion?? usar un for o un while?

Comment: revisa [ENUM](https://jarroba.com/enum-enumerados-en-java-con-ejemplos/)